# Why is this GitLab post-receive script terminated or stuck in a while loop?

Tags: bash, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, git-post-receive

After writing a `post-receive` script that looks for the latest `job.log` file that is created by the GitLab Runner CI, I'm noticing that the `post-receive` script gets terminated or stuck before it finds the latest `job.log` file. In particular it does not move beyond a while loop. Additionally, the GitLab Runner gives a `4:Deadline Exceeded` error.

### MWE

The MWE does the complete deployment, and uploads a repository to the GitLab server and runs the CI on the repository. However, it is not yet generalised well, hence it has (at least) the following requirements: System: Ubuntu 20.04, Architecture:AMD64.

```
git clone git@github.com:Deployment-Oneliners/Self-host-GitLab-Server-and-Runner-CI.git
cd Self-host-GitLab-Server-and-Runner-CI
git checkout post-receive
rm -r test/libs/*
chmod +x install-bats-libs.sh
./install-bats-libs.sh
./install_gitlab.sh -s -r
./test.sh
```

Then one can inspect the log of the `post-receive` script inside the GitLab docker with:

```
sudo docker ps -a
sudo docker exec -t -i ab15330e020f  /bin/bash
cd /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/@hashed/d4/73/d4735e3a265e16eee03f59718b9b5d03019c07d8b6c51f90da3a666eec13ab35.git/refs/keep-around/9514d16aafc1d741ba6a9ff47718d632fa8d435b
cat post_receive_log.txt
```

To uninstall the MWE completely, one can run: `./uninstall_gitlab.sh -y -h -r`.

### Relevant code

To identify where the code stops, I made the `post-receive` script export a lot of variables to the `post-receive-log.txt`. Here is the loop that searches for the most recent job log:

```
find_job_of_commit() {
    local search_path=$1
    local searched_commit=$2
    echo "in loop search_path=$search_path" >> "post_receive_log.txt"
    echo "in loop searched_commit=$searched_commit" >> "post_receive_log.txt"
    query_result=$(while ! find "$search_path" -name "job.log" | xargs grep "Checking out $searched_commit"; do sleep 10 ; done)
    echo "query_result=$query_result" >> "post_receive_log.txt"
}
```

### Output:

This outputs the following `post_receive_log.txt`:

```
repopath_to_artifacts=/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/artifacts/d4/73/d4735e3a265e16eee03f59718b9b5d03019c07d8b6c51f90da3a666eec13ab35
in loop search_path=/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/artifacts/d4/73/d4735e3a265e16eee03f59718b9b5d03019c07d8b6c51f90da3a666eec13ab35
in loop searched_commit=eb052e7d
```

So basically one can conclude the `post-receive` script is terminated during the `sleep 10` command, or that it is stuck in the while loop without being able to find the file. A more elaborate code revealed that it actually stopped after a `sleep 10` command. And it does not find the last job (the latest job nr was `31` in this run).

However, based on the `post_receive_log.txt` output, I can run the exact waiting command manually inside the GitLab docker, and there it *does* work:

```
root@127:/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/@hashed/d4/73/d4735e3a265e16eee03f59718b9b5d03019c07d8b6c51f90da3a666eec13ab35.git# while ! find "/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/artifacts/d4/73/d4735e3a265e16eee03f59718b9b5d03019c07d8b6c51f90da3a666eec13ab35" -name "job.log" | xargs grep "Checking out eb052e7d"; do sleep 10 ; done
/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/artifacts/d4/73/d4735e3a265e16eee03f59718b9b5d03019c07d8b6c51f90da3a666eec13ab35/2021_10_16/33/33/job.log:Checking out eb052e7d as master...
```

### Hypothesis I

I think perhaps the `@` symbol in the filepath of `repopath_to_artifacts` is proccessed differently in the command line than inside the bash script, leading to an invalid/nonexistant path in bash, but a valid path in the CLI.

### Hypothesis II

So my second thought is that the `post-receive` is terminated after a certain amount of seconds by GitLab. This migt be substantiated by the `4:Deadline Exceeded` message:
[image]

### Hypothesis III

The `find` command uses some kind of image of the directories that is not updated within a single shell script. (Seems unlikely to me and does not explain why the `post-receive` script would stop). However, it is substantiated by a manual test, if I run the `post-receive` script manually (within the Docker) with:

```
/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/@hashed/d4/73/d4735e3a265e16eee03f59718b9b5d03019c07d8b6c51f90da3a666eec13ab35.git
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/hooks/post-receive.d/./post-receive
f818b5eabfed71a70923bbf5186e31fc0806b6bc\n f818b5eabfed71a70923bbf5186e31fc0806b6bc\n repo_to_test_runner
```

Which works well for both failed and successfull jobs. Even directly after the `post-receive` job is terminated unsuccesfully, on the commit it previously couldn't find.

### Question

Why is the `post-receive` file terminated unexpectedly or stuck in the while loop?

Comment: It looks to me like youre whole script is just `while ! find -name "job.log" | xargs grep "$commit"; do sleep 10 ; done`. Why the `find` + some odd `'\n'` + `[[ ! -z grep`? Check your scripts with shellcheck!

Comment: Your suggestion significantly simplifies the code. Thank you! The code still terminates unexpectedly (or it is stuck in the while loop), whilst running the command manually does result in the file being found and the while loop being terminated. 

The artifacts you ask about like `\n` existed because I split the string containing multiple filepaths into an array to debug the while loop per file that was scanned and to test a for loop in stead, in case my `condition` in the while loop was causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hypothesis II is confirmed. The post-receive script is terminated after roughly 60 seconds. I do not yet know why. I determined this by logging an output every 2 seconds, looking at the log file while it is running and checking when it stops producing outputs. It stopped as soon as the `4:Deadline Exceeded.` message popped up, even though the debugging for loop that produced the output, still had 96 iterations to go.